# Erica CouchDB rewrites

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, couchdb, couchapp

When I upload documents using Erica into CouchDB it removes my rewrites. Is there a way to configure my rewrites in Erica? If so I've been unable to figure it out, any help would be great!

Comment: Ok I'm getting closer I realized Erica will just push any file or folder in my directory up as a field in my design doc, but I can only get the values to come out as strings, but instead it needs to be a JSON array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Got it! So simple... Just add a rewrites.json file to your app directory and it will push it up along with everything else.

Comment: is this the correct answer? Is it, and question, useful?

Comment: This was the correct answer a the time, however I haven't worked with CouchDB for quite a while, and I can't recall much of this problem. If you are having a similar issue it may be best to open a new question.